# How do I properly use onAuthStateChanged from firebase in react native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm a bit confused over the `firebase` function `onAuthStateChanged()`.

```
componentDidMount() {
fbAuth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) { //THIS TRIGGERS BOTH AT LOGIN AND REGISTRATION
    console.log("LOGGED IN");
  } else {
    //TRIGGERS WHEN LOGGING OUT; NOT WHEN FAILING TO LOGIN!
    console.log("LOGGED OUT");
  }
});
}
```

I thought that the if(user) block triggered when the user has logged in, but the console.log is also triggered when a new account is created. How do I make a conditional that only triggers at login (and not by creating a new account?)

Comment: what are you using react-native-firebase or web APIs (Expo)??

Comment: react-native-firebase :)

Comment: Creating a new user in firebase automaticly logs that user in. Thats why it triggers.

Comment: @André Kool Ah, I see, then it makes sense that it triggers, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
onAuthStateChanged(nextOrObserver, error, completed) returns function()
```

returns a **listener** function

Therefore you need to `listen` it when the *component is mounted* and `unlisten` when the *component is unmounted*

You need to make a separate Component if you want to listen specifically for Login

**Login.js** // Or whatever your login component is

```
componentDidMount() {
    // Bind the variable to the instance of the class.
    this.authFirebaseListener = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,  // For the loader maybe
        user, // User Details
        isAuth: true
      });
    });

  }

componentWillUnmount() {
   this.authFirebaseListener && this.authFirebaseListener() // Unlisten it by calling it as a function
}
```