# firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged() works weirdly

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a react project, where I want to provide the user globally accessible. For this I'm using useContext. My problem is that I have an `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){})` set up to monitor if there us a change. The code what I'm using for this:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (_user) { //Monitor changes 
    console.log("Auth state changed"); //Log if it changed
    if (_user) {
      //grab user's data from firestroe
      db.collection("users").doc(_user.uid).get() 
        .then(function (doc) {
          if (doc.exists) {
            user_profile = doc.data();
            setUser(user_profile);
          }
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
        });
    } else {
    }
  });
```

Unfortunately on the `console` what I see is that ist constantly logging that "Auth state changed". Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

[The console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv1ap.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Android onAuthStateChanged called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37673616/firebase-android-onauthstatechanged-called-twice)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49811230/how-do-i-properly-use-onauthstatechanged-from-firebase-in-react-native